# Style sheet contains ::after pseudo-element behaves differently in react js compared to html/css

Tags: css, reactjs

I am trying to use a simple timeline in reach js. the timeline is created using ul and li elements with appropriate styling. I got the code from net, and I first tried it in simple html with css and it worked fine. I then moved the styling into index.css of react js project, and then use the same styles in a component. I see a totally different behavior and not able to figure out the reason.

[image: Rendering difference between HTML/CSS versus React JS]

I am pasting the style sheet i used.

```css
  .timeline {
    width:500px;
    height: 20px;
    list-style: none;
    text-align: justify;
    margin: 80px auto;
    background: -webkit-gradient(left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(45%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(51%, rgba(191,128,11,1)), color-stop(57%, rgba(255,255,255,0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0)));
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 45%, rgba(191,128,11,1) 51%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 57%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
  }

  .timeline:after {display: inline-block; content: ""; width: 100%;}

  .timeline li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: #064213;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 1.2;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .timeline li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    content: attr(data-year);
    font-size: 12px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }

  .timeline li:nth-child(odd):before {
    top: -40px;
  }
  .timeline li:nth-child(even):before {
    bottom: -40px;
  }

  .timeline li:after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: attr(data-text);
    font-size: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }

  .timeline li:nth-child(odd):after {
    bottom: 0;
    margin-bottom: -10px;
    transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  }
  .timeline li:nth-child(even):after {
    top: 0;
    margin-top: -10px;
    transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  }
```

here is the HTML/JSX used

```html
<body>
    <ul  class="timeline">
      <li data-text='order placed' data-year='1/1/2020::45:30' ></li>
      <li data-text='order accepted' data-year='1/1/2020:9:45:42' ></li>
      <li data-text='order processed' data-year='1/1/2020:11:45:34' ></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Any idea why this issue is coming and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Problem

The problem appears to stem from `text-align: justify`. You'll only find support for `justify` in [react native](https://reactnative.dev/docs/text-style-props#textalign).

You can confirm this lack of support by running this React snippet below and see how `justify` works when not wrapped within the div `root`:

```js
const {Fragment} = React;

const Example = () => {
  return (
   <Fragment>
      <h1>React</h1>
      <ul className="timeline">
        <li data-text="order placed" data-year="1/1/2020::45:30"></li>
        <li data-text="order accepted" data-year="1/1/2020:9:45:42"></li>
        <li data-text="order processed" data-year="1/1/2020:11:45:34"></li>
      </ul>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.timeline {
  width: 500px;
  height: 20px;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: justify;
  margin: 80px auto;
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
    color-stop(45%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
    color-stop(51%, rgba(191, 128, 11, 1)),
    color-stop(57%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
    color-stop(100%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0))
  );
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
    color-stop(45%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
    color-stop(51%, rgba(191, 128, 11, 1)),
    color-stop(57%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
    to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0))
  );
  background: -o-linear-gradient(
    top,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 45%,
    rgba(191, 128, 11, 1) 51%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 57%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%
  );
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 45%,
    rgba(191, 128, 11, 1) 51%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 57%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%
  );
}

.timeline:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
}

.timeline li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #064213;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.timeline li:before {
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(data-year);
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.timeline li:nth-child(odd):before {
  top: -40px;
}

.timeline li:nth-child(even):before {
  bottom: -40px;
}

.timeline li:after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: attr(data-text);
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.timeline li:nth-child(odd):after {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
}

.timeline li:nth-child(even):after {
  top: 0;
  margin-top: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
}
.example {
  display: -ms-grid;
  display: grid;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    from(white),
    to(black)
  );
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, white, black);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, white, black);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Example created using Stackoverflow snippet"
    />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <h1>Native HTML</h1>
    <ul class="timeline">
      <li data-text="order placed" data-year="1/1/2020::45:30"></li>
      <li data-text="order accepted" data-year="1/1/2020:9:45:42"></li>
      <li data-text="order processed" data-year="1/1/2020:11:45:34"></li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Workaround

A workaround to this limitation would be to use [flexboxes](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) instead.

### Demo

[image: Edit Custom Timeline Component]

#### Code

**Timeline.js**

```js
import * as React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import "./Timeline.css";

const Timeline = ({ items }) => (
  <div className="container" style={{ width: items.length * 100 }}>
    <div className="timeline-line" style={{ width: items.length * 100 }} />
    <div className="timeline">
      {items.map(({ text, year }) => (
        <div
          key={text}
          className="timeline-item"
          data-text={text}
          data-year={year}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  </div>
);

Timeline.propTypes = {
  items: PropTypes.arrayOf(
    PropTypes.shape({
      text: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
      year: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    }).isRequired
  ).isRequired
};

export default Timeline;
```

**Timeline.css**

```css
.container {
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.timeline {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.timeline-line {
  position: absolute;
  height: 20px;
  background: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    from(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
    color-stop(45%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
    color-stop(51%, rgba(191, 128, 11, 1)),
    color-stop(57%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)),
    to(rgba(255, 255, 255, 0))
  );
  background: -o-linear-gradient(
    top,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 45%,
    rgba(191, 128, 11, 1) 51%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 57%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%
  );
  background: linear-gradient(
    to bottom,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 45%,
    rgba(191, 128, 11, 1) 51%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 57%,
    rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%
  );
}

.timeline-item {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: #064213;
  line-height: 1.2;
  position: relative;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.timeline-item:before {
  top: -40px;
  content: attr(data-year);
  font-size: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
}

.timeline-item:after {
  content: attr(data-text);
  font-size: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
  transform: translate(-50%, 100%);
}
```

**App.js**

```js
import Timeline from "./Timeline";
import "./styles.css";

const timelineItems = [
  { text: "order placed", year: "1/1/2020::45:30" },
  { text: "order accepted", year: "1/1/2020:9:45:42" },
  { text: "order processed", year: "1/1/2020:9:45:52" },
  { text: "order in packaging", year: "1/1/2020:9:46:02" },
  { text: "order shipped", year: "1/1/2020:11:55:32" }
];

const App = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <h1>Custom Timeline Component</h1>
    <Timeline items={timelineItems} />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

**styles.css**

```css
.app {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Matt. Thanks a lot.  This solved part of the problem, but still few issues remain. issue:1 if i put just 2 div of class "timeline-line" it will paint like o-----0---- instead of 0-----0. issue 2) if you put 4 items, the 3rd and 4th item gets overlapped like this 0----0----0-0---- issue 3) the nodes are supposed to be equally distributed on the time line. for example, if  we have 5 nodes it should be distributed as 0---0---0---0---0---0, if i hv just 2 items it should be distributed as 0---------0. i will look at this, and figure out to fix, but in case it is a small change please let me know.

Comment: understood! thank you very much. Nor sure, how the reply you put for the qn above is gone. I am pasting your reply here, in case someone finds it useful later. reply from Matt ==> That's one of the drawbacks in that you'll have to adjust for more or less timeline-items. Right now, it's set up for 3 items: Flex-Start----Center----Flex-End. If you add more you may need to calculate the flex-boxes to be evenly distributed and then adjust the layout to be: Flex-Start----Center----Center----Flex-End or if using less items: Flex-Start----Flex-End

Comment: Updated example to be more dynamic in spacing items! See demo.

Comment: Matt, Wow! it works perfectly. I have one question. How do i make the yellow lines length constant, say 1200px.  This time line would be used for representing so many events. I plan to build a component that would show 10 events in a line, and then next 10 as another line, so on and so forth. so when i reach a point i have less than 10 events, it would be good i can still retain the length of the line as 1200 px and the dots get distributed evenly on the line.

Comment: You can change these [two lines](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-timeline-component-forked-xd3zz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/Timeline.js:128-272). You can pass in a `width` prop and assign to the `style` property; or, you can remove both `style` properties and simply define a `width: 1200px;` CSS rule to both the `.container` and `.timeline-line` classes in [Timeline.css](https://codesandbox.io/s/custom-timeline-component-forked-xd3zz?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/Timeline.css).